# How to divide two columns in same table and append the result to the end of the table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not very proficient with SQL and I am struggling to divide two table columns in SQL and append the result to the end of the same table.

The end result is to have the division averages appended and stored to the end of Table 1.

```
select RefKey, HPProD / HPSalD as 'HPAvgD' From [Table1]
select RefKey, HPProSD / HPSalSD as 'HPAvgSD' From [Table1]
select RefKey, HPProT / HPSalT as 'HPAvgT' From [Table1]
select RefKey, HPProF / HPSalF as 'HPAvgF' From [Table1]
```

I currently have this but it does not do the latter - instead the division is output into its own temp table.

Comment: Sample data and expected result will be helpful.

Comment: why all those in different line rather in single line

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I guess it is because I am not very proficient

Comment: Does your table contain some column to insert those average values?

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran no it doesn't. Do I need to do this before I run the division?

Comment: It depends on your requirement which is not clear, do you need to store those AVG values? then you need to have columns for those avgs. If not then it's not needed, btw what do you mean by append?

Comment: Apologies - yes I do need to store them to the end of Table1

Comment: Then You need to have 4 extra columns HPAvgD,HPAvgSD,HPAvgT and HPAvgF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add computed columns.  For instance:

```
alter table table1
     add PHAvgD as (HPProD / nullif(HPSalD));
```

You can repeat this for each new column.

The advantage of this approach is that the values are calculated when they are fetched -- so the calculations are always accurate for new rows and updated column values.

Comment: Thanks for this method - so is there a risk using the other methods listed that the calculation won't match the rows being assessed in the maths?

Comment: @AWGIS . . . Yes.  The `update` only updates the table once, so it does not capture data changes afterwards (`insert`s, `update`s).  A computed problem should always be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

do you find something below to create new table from existing one

```
insert into table1 (RefKey,HPSalD,HPSalSD,HPSalT,HPSalF)   
select RefKey,HPProD / NULLIF(HPSalD,0) as HPAvgD,
     HPProSD / NULLIF(HPSalSD,0) as HPAvgSD,
   HPProT / NULLIF(HPSalT,0) as HPAvgT,
  HPProF / NULLIF(HPSalF,0) as HPAvgF from table1
```

Comment: That does create a new table but I would like it appended to the original.

Comment: @AWGIS edited there was multiple from so i removed one

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
create table [Table1] (RefKey int, HPProD int, HPSalD int)
insert into [Table1] values (1, 100, 20)

alter table [Table1] add HPAvgD int --If this colum is not in the table.
update [Table1] set HPAvgD = Case HPSalD when 0 then 0 else HPProD / HPSalD end
```

[**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/KIC46527)

For other column apply same rule with comma in same query.

Comment: I have tried this but the result does not append onto the end of the original table

Comment: @AWGIS Please check the demo.

Answer (score 1):

You need add 4 columns for all four averages and run the update statement given below,

```
UPDATE [Table1] 
    SET HPAvgD = Case when HPSalD =0 then 0 else HPProD / HPSalD end,
        HPAvgSD= Case when  HPSalD= 0 then 0 else HPProSD / HPSalSD end,
        HPAvgT = Case  when HPSalT= 0 then 0 else HPProT / HPSalT end,
        HPAvgF = Case  when HPSalF = 0 then 0 else HPProF / HPSalF end
```